# Multithreading & shared resource: Periodically copy data from buffer (data structure) to a file using C++

Tags: c++, timer, synchronization, c++14, mutex

My code has a data structure say for example "vector of vector of Strings. I've 2 threads:

Thread 1 is writing data to this data structure (buffer in RAM).

Thread 2 running in parallel which should copy data FROM the above buffer i.e data structure TO  a file for every "x" milliseconds.

I'm wondering how would I achieve this in C++ ? It should consider key points in problem statement like:

- The copy from buffer to file should happen only once in "X" milliseconds.
- Synchronization between both threads.

**EDITING THE QUERY WITH MORE DETAILS PER THE ASK**

I want to build a library (*.lib) & this library exposes some APIs hence it gets input data from EXE or any entity which uses my library through these APIs.

Say the data received by my library is in the form of a vector of strings.

```
FillLibraryDataStructure(std::vector<std::string>); // is the API of this library. Any app can call this API & pass a vector of string to this library.
```

Example app code:

```
for(int i=100; i<100;i))
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec = GetVectorOfString(); // GetVectorOfString from business logic
FillLibraryDataStructure(vec);
}
```

**Library code having a shared resource:**

Within library I've a 2D vector i.e. vector of vector of strings where all the vector of strings passed by application to this library are added as a new row in vecofvecofstr.

**SHARED RESOURCE:**

```
std::vector<std::vector<string>> vecofvecofstr;
```

**THREAD 1**: is copying the data it receives from  API to the data structure i.e. vector of vector of strings.

```
vecofvecofstr.push_back(vec);
```

**THREAD 2**: is copying the contents of this vector of vector of string (which was written to in 1st thread ) to files (XML, HTML etc..) for every "X" millisecond.

Few more points about thread1:

1. Thread 1 should be running continuously i.e. as and when application calls the API the data received should be put to the data structure vecofvecofstr.
2. After "X" milliseonds of copying the data to the buffer, 2nd thread should get started & it should copy all the stuff that was dumped to buffer till date. Again after "X" millisonds the thread 2 should pause & wait for "X" ms.

How do I achieve this. Here the 1st thread is the default one in which my library code would be running.

How do I achieve this using C++?

Comment: This is a very broad question and commonly known as the producer consumer problem.

Comment: It isn't clear if thread 1 may read from the data structure too.  C++11 has the necessary mutexes and `std::lock_guard` to use the mutexes easily.  You'd also need a timer, or just make the thread sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable>` to your advantage.  And a double buffer would keep locking to a minimum.

`std::condition_variable>` is the nearest thing to an event the std has to offer, its use is a bit contrived, but it works.

The example below uses a double buffer so you can keep on buffering data while thread 2 is saving to file, without locking.

The std:condition_variable is used so your application can exit without waiting.  This is only needed if you want your application to exit promptly, else you can use a timer.  The call to `notify_all()` will prevent the wait_for() from timing out, and wake the writing thread immediately, so it can exit without waiting for the timeout to occur.  See ref at :http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Header:

```
#include <mutex>

// a generic double buffer
template<typename _Data>
class DoubleBuffer
{
private:
   std::mutex mutex_;

   std::vector<std::vector<_Data>> storeBuffer_;
   std::vector<std::vector<_Data>> saveBuffer_;

public:
   void lock() { mutex_.lock(); }
   void unlock() { mutex_.unlock();}

   auto& GetStoreBuffer() { return storeBuffer_; }
   auto& GetSaveBuffer()  { return saveBuffer_; }
   auto& Swap()
   {
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
     std::swap(storeBuffer_, saveBuffer_);
   }
};
```

In your library:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// As an example, could be inside a class, or struct 
static std::condition_variable exiting;
static std::mutex lk_exiting;

static DoubleBuffer<std::string> yourBuffer;

void FillLibraryDataStructure(std::vector<std::string> strings)
{
    // the lock is only for the duration of a swap - very short at worst.
    std::lock_guard<DoubleBuffer<std::string>> lock(yourBuffer);
    yourBuffer.GetStoreBuffer().emplace_back(strings);
}

void StoreLoop()
{
    for(;;)
    {
       {   // wait_for() unlocks lk_exiting, doc says lock should
           // be set before cv is triggered.
           std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk_exiting;
           if (std::cv_status::no_timeout == exiting.wait_for(lk_exiting, 60s))
               break;  // app is exiting
       }

      yourBuffer.Swap();

      auto& stringsToSave = GetSaveBuffer();
      // save...  You do have plenty of time.
    }
}

// as an example.  A destructor would be a good place for this
void Exit_Application() 
{
  // stops the wait_for operation in StoreLoop()
  exiting.notify_all();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The example code is not very clear as to why are we using 2 buffers savebuffer and storebuffer then why swapping. How is condition variable and muted used. Request to kindly explain.

Comment: In the code you have given in FillLibraryDataStructure() - I see you are passing DoubleBuffer<std::string> as an argument to template type lock_guard<std::mutex> whereas lock_guard can only accept std::mutex. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer regard to your general question, there is two possible options:

1- use some wait, signal commands to sleep and wake threads in parallel

2- use some sleep to provide X milliseconds in reading thread

If you need better answer, give more details